# Jquery function cannot fire event from new data in webgrid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Wasn't exactly sure how to title this problem, but essentially what my issue is, is calling a jquery function based on a new elements that gets put into my WebGrid. However, my webgrid is populated on toggling of radio buttons. The grid then gets updated with new data by an ajax call. Therefore, no page refresh is done and my elements exist in my grid, but my javascript does not know about them.

Below is some of my code.

Webgrid:

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-bordered",
            headerStyle: "thead-default",
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("account_number", "Account Number", canSort: true),
                grid.Column("last_name", "Last Name", canSort: true),
                grid.Column("first_name", "First Name", canSort: true),
                grid.Column("middle_name", "Middle Name", canSort: true),
                grid.Column("reject_reviewed", "Reviewed", canSort: true, format: (item) => Html.CheckBox("completed", (bool)(item.reject_reviewed == 1), new { disabled = "disabled" })),
                grid.Column("comment", "Comments", format: (item) =>
                    new HtmlString(
                        Html.ActionLink("Add", "RejectAddComment", controller, new RejectCommentViewModel { reject_id = item.id, account_number = item.account_number, reject_message = item.reject_message },
                            htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", id = "btnCreate", @class = "" }).ToString()
                                    + " | " +
                        Html.ActionLink("View", "RejectViewComment", controller, new RejectCommentViewModel { reject_id = item.id, account_number = item.account_number, reject_message = item.reject_message },
                            htmlAttributes: new { data_modal = "", id = "btnCreate", @class = "" }).ToString())),
                grid.Column("reject_message", "Reject Message", canSort: true)))
```

javascript:

```
    $(function () {

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("body").on("click", 'a[data-modal]', function (e) {

        // hide dropdown if any
        $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');


        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {


            $('#myModal').modal({
                /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function bindForm(dialog) {

    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    //Refresh
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the line to this

```
$("#scroll-grid").on("click", "#btnCreate", function (e)
```

and the javascript event now fires.

The first element must be a parent element, and after the click event must be the element you are looking for the event of.

Answer (score 0):

Change your event binding from:

```
 $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
```

To

```
 $("body").on("click", 'a[data-modal]',function (e) {
```

and it is better to use a a better selector than body, something like you grid id or class

By the way this is a famous issue, [googled](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20on%20after%20ajax)

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Edited the above javascript, however I am receiving the same results.

Comment: are you getting any errors in console, or it is just not firing the event?

Comment: Solved above, thanks for your help. Just had to switch some element id's around.